# Pandas DataFrame: Removing duplicate rows based on condition in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv)

df.head()
ID  Year    status
223725  1991    No
223725  1992    No
223725  1993    No
223725  1994    No
223725  1995    No
```

I have many unique `IDs` and I want to remove duplicate rows based on the columns `ID` and `status`.

1. If an `ID` has a value of `Yes` in `status` then only that
   row is retained, all other rows with a `status` value of
   `No` are removed for that specific `ID`.
2. If an `ID`  has `No` in every observation in `status`
   then retain any row specific to that `ID`.

For example, in the DataFrame below, only the row where 68084329 has a value of `Yes` in status should be kept i.e. the last row, all other rows with `No` are dropped.

```
 ID         Year    status
68084329    1991    No
68084329    1992    No
68084329    1993    No
68084329    1994    No
68084329    1995    No
68084329    1996    No
68084329    1997    No
68084329    1998    No
68084329    1999    No
68084329    2000    No
68084329    2001    No
68084329    2002    No
68084329    2003    No
68084329    2004    No
68084329    2005    No
68084329    2006    No
68084329    2007    No
68084329    2008    No
68084329    2010    No
68084329    2011    No
68084329    2012    Yes
```

How to I drop duplicate rows according to the above conditions?

Comment: Please get used to providing sample df as a callable line of code, you could create a dummy df or get it from your original data with `df.head(10).to_dict('list')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
# sort by status so that No comes before Yes
df = df.sort_values('status')

# pick the last row, it will either be Yes or No
df = df.groupby('ID').last()
```

Comment: beat me to it! Just a warning for @MIMA if there are two rows with `Yes` for the same `ID` this will only keep one of them

Comment: Thank you both for the input. Luckily there's no rows with Yes for the same ID.